# Computation with maximum and minimum

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Can someone explain the steps for the equality
$$(Z+X\wedge Y)\vee (X\vee Y)=(Z\vee (X\vee Y-X\wedge Y))+ (X\wedge Y)$$

And $\vee=\max(),\wedge=\min()$ are the usual max/min notation for rv. I don't even know if the distributive property etc. applies here.

Edit: here is the translated expression
$$\max(Z+\min(X,Y),\max(X,Y))=\max(Z,\max(X,Y)-\min(X,Y))+ (\min(X,Y))$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a:=X\wedge Y$ and $b := X\vee Y$. Then the statement can be rewritten as

$min (Z+a,b) = min(Z,b-a) + a$

And from there it is easier to understand it.

Comment: Ah very nice and so simple! Thank you.

Comment: Tip: There are LaTeX commands for min and max: `\min`, `\max`. That will typeset them as $\min$ and $\max$.